# Oracle blocks NET6 migration - Detected package version outside of dependency constraint

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am currently migrating our main NET Core 3.1 app to NET 6. Our database access layer is encapsulated into a class library using EF Core 3.1 that also needs migrating to a newer version. In that lib, there is logic to access 2 databases, Azure Sql und Oracle Sql.

The [Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/) nuget package is not yet available for NET6.

`dotnet restore` gives the following warning:

```
warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 5.21.4 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 5.0.9 && < 6.0.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.0 was resolved.
```

Running a query against Oracle throws a `TypeLoadException`

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Method 'AppendIdentityWhereCondition' in type 'Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.OracleUpdateSqlGenerator' from assembly 'Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.21.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' does not have an implementation.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OracleServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddEntityFrameworkOracle>b__0_4(ServiceCollectionMap b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.TryAddProviderSpecificServices(Action`1 serviceMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OracleServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkOracle(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.OracleOptionsExtension.ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices(IDbContextOptions options, ServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|4_0(IDbContextOptions options, ConcurrentDictionary`2 configurations)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at OracleLib.MyDbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options)
   at App.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\app\Program.cs:line 39
   at App.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

I then tried splitting the Azure Sql part and Oracle Sql part, with the latter targeting *only* NET5. I then `dotnet pack`'ed both libs and included them in an NET6 app. But again, I am getting the above warning and typeload exception.

**Oracle effectively keeps me from migrating to NET6**. Is there any way I can tell the oracle lib to use its own lower version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` and call it a day?

Comment: Fyi; Oracle EF Core 6 support is planned to be available by [the end of the month](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/201#issuecomment-975733908)

Comment: [6.21.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/6.21.4) released